# How to cleanly uninstall ansible

Tags: python, linux, pip, ansible, uninstallation

Running debian jessie

I installed Ansible using the following procedure:

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-yaml python-pip python-jinja2 python-paramiko pip
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
cd ansible
git submodule update --init --recursive
sudo make install
```

Is there a way to cleanly uninstall Ansible that does not involve sifting through my directory tree and deleting?

The aim is to reinstall Ansible version 1.9 instead of the latest 2.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to install **checkinstall**, run the install again under checkinstalls control, and then use dpkg to remove things.

https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall

Answer (score 2):

There is a directory list in the source code repo telling you which directories ( and files ) are created. This is used to build the .deb package, but you can easily use it the other way around:

[packaging/debian/ansible.dirs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/packaging/debian/ansible.dirs)

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed on redhat centos based systems 
you can do below to uninstall ansible cleanly and similar command for ubuntu debian based systems

rpm -qa | grep ansible | xargs rpm -e

rpm -qa | grep -i epel | xargs rpm -e

else yum remove ansible

Comment: doesn't work anymore.  rpm: no packages given for erase

Answer (score 1):

As I see you cloned ansible from git. Try to remove ansible folder, but first, go to cloned folder and write

```
make uninstall
```

then

```
cd ..
rm -r ansible_folder
```

and dependent folders, files for example '/etc/ansible' folder.

Comment: Unfortunately recent versions (all?) don't have an uninstall rule in the Makefile

Answer (score 0):

I had built ansible 2.1.1 from source then wanted to downgrade to 2.1.0 using yum.  The trick i learned was to go to `/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and deleting the `ansible-2.1.1.0-py2.7.egg-info` directory.  In my case, using yum properly added files to /etc/ansible and /usr/bin, but as long as the old (newer version number) egg was there, then `ansible --version` continued to show the newer version number.

Answer (score -1):

After removing ansible using `dnf remove ansible` uninstall python and reinstall ansible it will show the newer version.